# PHP + mod_fastcgi + suexec can't read vars set via SetEnv in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-fastcgi, setenv

We have PHP running via mod_fastcgi + suexec and it seems that PHP processes run this way don't see environment variables set via `SetEnv` in a `.htaccess` file. I checked via a perl script and a shell script (both run via `mod_cgid`) that SetEnv indeed sets a variable (i.e. doing so is allowed by `AllowOverride` and `mod_env` is loaded). And I checked via `$_SERVER`, `$_ENV`, `getenv()`,
`$HTTP_ENV_VARS` and `phpinfo()` that PHP does not see the variable. I have not tried to find a proper solution, but I will post an answer that is a decent workaround.

Comment: Have you tried `SetEnvIf` instead? `SetEnvIf` is processed early, `SetEnv` is processed late - I don't know whether that makes any difference in this instance? (By moving `SetEnv` to a VitualHost context it will effectively be processed earlier.)

Comment: I did try SetEnvIf - same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who encounter the same problem, an inconvenient but quick workaround is to copy the relevant `SetEnv`-lines from the `.htaccess` files to the `VirtualHost` configuration blocks of the corresponding domain and restart Apache. Variables set this way seem to be visible to PHP.